# Saving images on Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to save images using their file paths but every time that I kill the Xcode simulator and restart it, the location of the images changes and my imageView is blank. I know for a fact that the location changes because I print out the file path when I try to pick an image from the photo library and it's different each time.

I access the URL of the UIImage

```
    let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
    let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as! URL
```

After which I save the URL as a string to my realm database. I've tried converting it to string via all of these

```
    let imageFilePath = url.relativeString
    let imageFilePath = url.absoluteString
    let imageFilePath = url.relativePath
```

but none of them worked. I'm a newbie to Swift so let me know if I've missed any key details needed.

Comment: Every app is sandboxed. You can't save the whole image path. Every time your app run it will be a different path. You need to save the image directory and its name and recreate your url.

Comment: So how would I do that?

Comment: Where are you saving your image? The url of the image is temporary. You need to write the image to the documents directory.

Comment: What kind of image do you need to save? PNG, JPEG, HEIC?

Comment: The photos I'm using are all from the base photo library in Xcode. So if I save it to the documents directory and use that URL, I should be able to access it each time?